# Merge two git repositories that have been splitted in the past

Tags: git, merge, repository

I have two git repositories that have been separated 2 years ago, and we would like to merge them to get only 1 repository again (keeping the 2 years of work in the history if possible..).

When the split was made, we deleted in each repository the files that we wanted to keep in the other repo.

So how should I proceed to merge these repo ?

The branch (develop/master/..) of the 1st reopsitory, have been deleted in the 2nd one because they were not used (that's why the split was made...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, yes, it's possible to merge two branches/repos with unrelated histories.

For the main branch you would use `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories`:

```
git clone URL/repoA
cd repoA
git checkout main
git remote add repoB URL/repoB
git fetch repoB
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories repoB/main
```

After resolving any conflicts that arise, you should have a starting point for development on this merged repo. This will make a somewhat weird history, with two separate prongs to different initial commits, but there should be no problem with that.

The problem I foresee here is with any other branches that still exist in either repo. You'll want them to have the files from the other repo too, for consistency. I hope you don't have too many!

Some options I can see:

- Dev/feature branches: rebase them onto the newly merged starting point?
- If you have an ongoing `develop` branch, merging main back into it after the unrelated merge above should do the trick. That solution might also work for other active dev and feature branches.
- Historical/maintenance branches from old releases: tough. Do an unrelated merge from the commit at the right time in the other repo? Or if they're just historical and you're not using them anymore, leave them unmerged?

Comment: Now I have only 1 repo with the 2 branches : develop, and the other one (named "test_base" created from develop years ago) that I want to merge with develop .
But in develop history I deleted our "tests" folder, and in test_base history I have the deletion of all the folders except "tests".
When I make a PR with test_base => develop, I get conflicts on A LOT of things, I resolved by taking develop for all folders except for tests folder where I take source branch.
But the PR merge commit shows deletion of a lot of files that are not in the tests folder instead of keeping develop state, why?

Comment: @LiohAu I'm not sure I fully follow what you did. What I would do before creating the PR, though, is make sure I do all the merging in my sandbox, where I'm resolving the conflicts, and not let GitHub create the real merge. You should you submit a PR that can be fast-forward merged, i.e., in the PR branch, make sure you merge in (and fix) the branch you want to submit that PR onto. Does that make sense?

Comment: The fact that the branches you're merging mutually delete files each used to have could be causing the trouble, though. In my use case my histories were actually disjoint from the beginning. In your use case, the histories were once common, then spliced, and now you're merging them again. So doing the merge correctly might require more care.

Comment: Merge done ! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to know it worked!